# can we call an android activity from Phonegap project?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm Developing an android application.

I've created some codings using HTML5 and javascript for android. And created a signature capturing application in Native JAva

I wanted to include the Native Signature capture coding in the HTML5 application. Because the signature capturing in the HTML5 is not working perfect for touch devices.

is it possible to call a native android activity from the HTML5 phonegap android application????

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

For doing the same you need to add cordova lib to your android project and moreover create a plugin in android by extending the `Plugin` class.

The overrided method named `execute()` is there that you can call from your javascripts.

Remember you need to define the path of the class containing execute folder to the `config.xml`.

Please visit below for complete guide.

[Android Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any Java Native code call be called without using any plugin as following.

Follow The following Steps.

1) Replace the following code with your existing DroidGap Activity.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init(); // Calling this is necessary to make this work
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

    /* "this" points the to the object of the current activity. "MainActivity" is used to refer "this" object in JavaScript as in Step 3. */

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

2 Add the custom function in current (this) activity as following.

```
    public void customFunctionCalled() {
    Log.e("Custom Function Called", "Custom Function Called");
}
```

3 Now call this function from your HTML/JavaScript code as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callNewActivity() {
    window.MainActivity.customFunctionCalled();
}
```

Comment: I have used this number of times, It works fine, you must have made some error

Comment: did you use java code as it is make sure below three lines are there in your code and in same order
  super.init(); // Calling this is necessary to make this work
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

    /* "this" points the to the object of the current activity. "MainActivity" is used to refer "this" object in JavaScript as in Step 3. */

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");